# Difference between ways of sorting linked lists c++

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I was thinking about ways of sorting a linked list and I came up with two different ways (using BubbleSort, because I'm relatively new at programming and it is the simplest algorithm for me). Example struct:

```
struct node {
  int value;
  node *next;
};
```

The two different methods:

- Rearranging the list elements
- Doing something like `swap(root->value, root->next->value)`

I did some Google searches on the subject, and from the looks of it, the first method seems to be more popular. From my experience, such that it is, rearranging the list is more complicated than simply swapping the actual node values. Is there any benefit in rearranging the whole list, and if yes, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two advantages:

1) Other pointers might exist, pointing to nodes in this list. If you rearrange the list, these pointers will still point to the same values they pointed to before the sorting; if you swap values, they won't. (Which one of these two is better depends on the details of your design, but there are designs in which it is better if they remain pointing to the same values.)

2) It doesn't matter much for a list of mere ints, but eventually you might be sorting a list of more complex things, so that swapping values is very expensive or even impossible.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Beta, it's better to rearrange the nodes (via the next pointers) than it is to swap node data.

If actually using a bubble sort or any sort that "swaps" nodes via the pointers, swap the next (or head) pointers to the two nodes to be swapped first, then swap those two nodes next pointers. This handles both the adjacent node case where 3 pointers are rotated, and the normal case where 2 pairs of pointers are swapped.

Another simple option is to create an new empty list (node * pNew = NULL;) for the sorted list. Remove a node from the original list one at a time and insert that node into the sorted list in order, or scan the original list for the largest node, remove that node and prepend the sorted list with that node.

If the list is large and speed is important, than bottom up merge sorts are much faster.